# Flutter - go_router redirection method calls multiple times when redirecting to some particular screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I am using the `go_router` package for routing and everything is working unless 1 router whenever I try to go to that router the redirection method of `go_router` is being called multiple times, Does anyone know the reason

How to minimize the call of redirection method?

Comment: It could be a redirection loop but there is no way to tell without the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you managed to solve this but putting this out in case someone else runs into this.

In my case this happened because I hade redirection implemented in two different places, **top-level** and **route-level**

I had the 3 below paths:

- `/home`
- `/profile_form`

In top-level redirection I implemented the following:

```
if(user.validProfile==false)
  return '/home'
```

in `/home` path-level redirection i implemented the following

```
if(user.validProfile==false)
 return '/profile_form'
```

The issue stems from the fact that any route request goes Through top level redirection, every time, even if it came from a redirection.

I had this loop `/home` -> `/profile_form` ->`/home` -> `/profile_form` ...

I resolved this by ensuring redirection happens at the top level whenever possible,

I also drew all the links between the routes, it should be a Direct Acyclic graph taking into account the contol logic ofc, regardless of condition.

hope this helps